# Link section within page with slash (/) and not hash (#) without reloading the page

Tags: pages, seo, linking

**So here is a requirement:**

1. Client wants a page template where there is two level menu on left
   side of the page.
2. That menu can link to any page, post, category or a section within same page.
3. The menu which links to a section within same page should be slash linked and **not** # linked for the purpose of SEO.

**And this is how we have implemented it:**

1. Based on one requirement I have developed a custom page template
   with sidebar on left.
2. Using WordPress menu I registered multiple menus with menu items as
   per the requirement.
3. I developed a custom widget which provides an option to select a
   menu to be assigned to that page. So far all good....

**And here comes the question:**

1. How do I link the section within same page with `/` and not `#`?
2. For example if the page is `http://example.com/event-page/` and there
   is a section within page content say "Get Passes" and also a menu
   corresponding to it on left. Now what client wants is that the menu
   shall **not** be linked like `http://example.com/event-page/#get-passes`
   but rather `http://example.com/event-page/get-passes/`
3. Needless to say that it should just scroll down to that particular
   section without reloading the page.

Comment: lol, is there an actual justification (ROI) for making all the effort that will be required to make it work? I mean actual article by google or some other authority? (need to tag this question under "crazy clients")

Comment: Agree with Mark.  You are going to end up in a combination of JS and .htaccess rewrites to do something that really doesn't need to be done and will be a maintenance nightmare.  Page SEO is more than just URLs...

Comment: @MarkKaplun - Yeah its kind of funny and challenging. I do agree that it may not be worth putting so much of efforts. I searched if there is any article from google that # links are bad for SEO and you must go for / links or something like that. But did not find something like that, so thought to ask here :)

Comment: there is just too many details to take care of - JS, duplicate content, browser history maybe, page caching if you use.... too many thing that might go wrong. Realy needs some huge proven benefit to even start coding such thing

Comment: This works? /index.php#your-anchor

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) to change the browser URL without reloading a page, and jQuery's [`scrollTop`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) method to scroll to the top of a specific element (and there are [VanillaJS equivalents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917921/cross-browser-javascript-not-jquery-scroll-to-top-animation) too). This will mimic the functionality of `#` anchors.

However, like what Mark said, what your client wants is *really* weird. It is hard to maintain and keep working, and it might even hurt your client. Here's [a case study](https://www.wired.com/2011/02/gawker-learns-the-hard-way-why-hash-bang-urls-are-evil/) that you might want to show him/her.